# How to add actions to an ios alert

Tags: ios, objective-c, uialertview

How can I add an action to all of the "other" buttons?

This is how I am displaying the Alert:

```
- (IBAction)testCalAdd:(id)sender {
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
    initWithTitle:@"Select week"
    message:@"Which week will you be attending?"
    delegate:self
    cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
    otherButtonTitles:@"AIG Thermal $1 Million Grand Prix", @"DC VII", @"DC VI", @"DC V", @"DC IV", @"DC III", @"DC II", @"DC I", nil];
    [alert show];
}
```

Comment: The same way you handle the "Cancel" button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with a `UIAlertViewDelegate`, but it's much easier to use [PSAlertView](https://github.com/steipete/PSAlertView).

Copied from another answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19618952/uialertview-indexbutton/19621059#19621059).

```
PSAlertView *alert = [[PSAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Contact"];
[alert setCancelButtonWithTitle:@"Dismiss" block:^{}];
[alert addButtonWithTitle:@"Call" block:^{
    NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"telprompt://%@", phoneNumber];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL urlWithString:urlString];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
 }];
[alert show];
```

Comment: Adding a separate block for each button is not necessarily "much easier". It depends on the needs of the app and the buttons.

Comment: The savings is not necessarily in the amount of code, but rather in how readable the code is. All the code for the UIAlertView is in one spot. This is opposed to creating the UIAlertView in one place and having a delegate method called in another. Additionally, since many view controllers have multiple alerts, the delegate doesn't get overloaded.

Answer (score 2):

Check the delegate method:

`-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex;`

When you press any button in your alert, the index is showed in that method.